# CodeIgniter validation and checkbox

Tags: codeigniter, validation, checkbox

i have problem with my checkbox i want to add validation but i don't know how should look my name field in validation rule.

My view

```
<?php   
   foreach( $tab1 as $row){
?>   
    <a>
      <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'id_user_'.$row->id_user; ?>" value="   <?php echo $row->id_user; ?>"  />

    </a>
       <?php
```

When i do this i get result (name of the checkbox )for example:

```
id_user_1
id_user_2

id_user_3
```

Now i want to add validation but:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules(' WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE ??? ', 'User','required');
```

EDIT:

```
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_uzytkownika', 'Uzytkownika','required');



if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    $todo = array(
            'tytul_projektu'=>$this->input->post('tytul_projektu'),
            'opis_projektu'=>$this->input->post('opis_projektu'),
            'data_zakonczenia'=>$this->input->post('datepicker')
            );

    $user_projekty = array(
            'id_uzytkownika'=>$this->input->post('id_uzytkownika'),
            'id_projektu'=>$this->input->post('id'),
            );



    $users = array();
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                if(strpos($key, 'id_uzytkownika') === 0)
                {
                    $users[] = $value;
                }  
            }

$this->Todo_model->add($todo,$user_projekty,$users);
```

VIEW:

```
<?php   
   foreach( $tab1 as $row){
    ?>   
    <a>
      <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'id_uzytkownika['.$row->id_uzytkownika.']'; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->id_uzytkownika; ?>"  />
```

MODEL:

> ```
> function add($data,$data2,$users)
> {
>     $this->db->insert('projekty', $data);
> ```
>
> $id = $this->db->insert_id('projekty');
>   $data2['id_projektu'] = $id;
>
> $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM uzytkownicy");
>
> foreach($users as $user)    {
>
> ```
>   $data2['id_uzytkownika'] = $user;
>
>   $this->db->insert('projekty_uzytkownicy', $data2);  }
>
>   return $query->result();
>
> }
> ```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594820/how-to-set-form-validation-rules-for-codeigniter-dynamically, I use something very like the 2nd answer there.

Comment: You might want to consider using [Arrays as field names](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields). Also [these](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/109826/) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498505/validating-multidimensional-arrays-in-code-igniter-with-form-validation-library) might be helpful.

Comment: When i try do this  `$this->form_validation->set_rules('tab1[]', 'User','required');`  OR  this `$this->form_validation->set_rules('tab1[id_user]', 'User','required'); ` in view i get always please insert User :(

Comment: Try $this->form_validation->set_rules('tab1[id_user.i]', 'User','required');

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can take with this. Using your existing code, the first would be to create a loop that defines all unique input names.

```
foreach($users as $user) {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_user_'.$user->id_user, 'User','required');
}
```

However, this logic would require every checkbox to be checked. Which I am not sure in what circumstance this would be used for.

Another approach would be to change your html a little bit. 
Instead of

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'id_user_'.$row->id_user; ?>" 
       value="<?php echo $row->id_user; ?>"  />
```

you can try using something like

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'id_user['.$row->id_user.']'; ?>" 
       value="1"  />
```

This way you could make a form validation rule based on `id_user` instead of unique names.

Comment: the last method almost work but look at EDIT in my first post, i have users array , and when i want to save it to database i get error: `Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'` how can i fix it ?

Comment: Can you post the `Todo_model add` method? The reason you are getting an error is because the `$users` object is an array. If the `add` method is not handling arrays, then you need to put the `add` method inside the `foreach loop`.

`if(strpos($key, 'id_user') === 0) {
// $users[] = $value;
$this->Todo_model->add($value);  
}`